# Why is my jpg corrupted after transferring over shm in c?

Tags: c

Summary: I am working on a multithreaded application (both the proxy and cache are multithreaded). I am passing a request the client (client is a black box, cannot see the code) makes to the proxy, and the proxy connects with a cache to query for the file. The proxy and cache share a message queue for the requests, and a POSIX shared memory channel for the data. If the request path is not found in the cache, then I post to the shared memory channel a -1. If it is found, I send back a concatenated string (size of data chunk|data) thru the shared memory channel instead. The proxy determines the status from the shared memory channel and sends the response back to the client, followed by the data if it exists.

The problem: I send back the perfect amount of data and have no issues, client and proxy filesizes and chunks sent/received match. I can also print the data and see that it APPEARS to be the same in both the proxy and cache (the characters are really weird). But when I go to open the jpg which the client wrote from the data it received, it is corrupted. I have scoured this code for days, but cannot find the reason.

I have a handler function for a proxy I made. It is ran infinitely inside the server, and waits until there is a request to serve:

```
ssize_t proxy_worker_handler(custom_struct *ctx, const char *path, void *arg)
{
    int segment_to_lock_into = *(int *)arg % GLOB_NSEGMENTS;

    size_t filesize = 0;

    mq_send(COMMAND_CHANNEL_ID, path, BUFSIZE, 1);

    data_channel current_channel = GLOB_DATA_CHANNEL_SEGMENTS[segment_to_lock_into];

    // Take proxy ownership of this segment for now
    sem_wait(current_channel.proxy_sem);

    // Wait until we can read, writer sends the signal
    sem_wait(current_channel.reader_sem);

    // Now we can read, see if file was found and send proper header
    if (strncmp(current_channel.data, "-1", strlen("-1")) == 0)
    {
        gfs_sendheader(ctx, GF_FILE_NOT_FOUND, 0);
        sem_post(current_channel.writer_sem);
    }
    else
    {
        // Get the filesize
        filesize = (size_t)atoi(current_channel.data);
        gfs_sendheader(ctx, GF_OK, filesize);
        sem_post(current_channel.writer_sem);

        // Now receive data
        int curr_received = 0;
        int delimiter, data_len;
        int padding_size = 10;
        char *data_str;
        char data_len_str[padding_size];
        while (curr_received < (int)filesize)
        {
            // Wait to be able to read
            sem_wait(current_channel.reader_sem);

            data_str = "";
            memset(data_len_str, 0, padding_size);

            // Break up the memory segment, to get size and string sent
            data_str = strstr(current_channel.data, "|") + 1;
            delimiter = (data_str - 1) - current_channel.data;
            for (int i = 0; i < delimiter; i++)
                data_len_str[i] = current_channel.data[i];
            data_len = atoi(data_len_str);

            printf("%s", data_str);

            // Use the above info to send the data
            curr_received += data_len;
            gfs_send(ctx, data_str, (size_t)data_len);

            sem_post(current_channel.writer_sem);
        }
        printf("%d of %zu\n", curr_received, filesize);
    }

    // Free up the segment for proxy workers waiting
    sem_post(current_channel.proxy_sem);

    return filesize;
}
```

I also have a cache worker, which is called infinitely as well but handles itself:

```
void *cache_worker(void *arg)
{
    char *path;
    int fd;
    struct stat st;
    char filesize[21];
    size_t batch_read, start_point;
    int segment_to_lock_into = *(int *)arg % GLOB_NSEGMENTS;

    free(arg);

    data_channel current_channel = GLOB_DATA_CHANNEL_SEGMENTS[segment_to_lock_into];

    while (1)
    {

        // Receive the request path from the boss
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_lock);

        while (steque_isempty(&queue) == 1)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queue_cond, &queue_lock);
        path = steque_pop(&queue);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_lock);

        fd = simplecache_get(path);
        sleep(cache_delay);

        // Because strdup uses malloc
        free(path);

        // Take cache ownership of this segment for now
        sem_wait(current_channel.cache_sem);

        // Now, see if the file exists
        if (fd == CACHE_FAILURE)
        {
            sem_wait(current_channel.writer_sem);

            // Write and then increment the read semaphore, so the proxy knows to read it
            memset(current_channel.data, 0, GLOB_SEGSIZE);
            memcpy(current_channel.data, "-1", strlen("-1"));
            sem_post(current_channel.reader_sem);
            close(fd);
        }
        else
        {
            // Tell the reader the size of the file first
            sem_wait(current_channel.writer_sem);

            fstat(fd, &st);
            snprintf(filesize, 21, "%ld", st.st_size);

            memset(current_channel.data, 0, GLOB_SEGSIZE);
            memcpy(current_channel.data, filesize, 21);

            sem_post(current_channel.reader_sem);

            // Open the file and send the data
            int padding_size = 10;
            char data[GLOB_SEGSIZE];
            char to_send[GLOB_SEGSIZE];
            batch_read = 0, start_point = 0;
            while ((int)(batch_read = pread(fd, data, (size_t)(GLOB_SEGSIZE - padding_size), start_point)) > 0)
            {
                sem_wait(current_channel.writer_sem);

                memset(to_send, 0, GLOB_SEGSIZE);
                memset(current_channel.data, 0, GLOB_SEGSIZE);

                snprintf(to_send, GLOB_SEGSIZE, "%zu|%s", batch_read, data);

                memcpy(current_channel.data, to_send, (size_t)GLOB_SEGSIZE);

                start_point += batch_read;

                printf("%s", data);

                sem_post(current_channel.reader_sem);
            }
            printf("%zu of %s\n", start_point, filesize);
        }

        // Free up the segment for cache workers waiting
        sem_post(current_channel.cache_sem);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: First problem I noticed: You're not adding a null terminator to `data_len_str`.

Comment: Would that cause an issue with anything? The `data_len` variable comes out fine when I print it

Comment: That was a mistake, I forgot about the `memset()` that zeroes `data_len_str` first.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the parts of the code that read and write the jpg file.

Comment: `while ((int)(batch_read = pread` inside of `cache_worker` is reading the file on the cache and then sending it back to the proxy with `memcpy(current_channel.data)`, which is a shared memory segment I read/write to...and then `gfs_send(ctx, data_str, (size_t)data_len);` inside `proxy_worker_handler` is sending the file received from the cache in `current_channel.data` to the client, which is a black box that takes in the chunks I send and downloads the file for me to view.

Comment: So the code that reads and writes the files is not here, this is just the code for communicating between the threads.

Comment: Yes basically, the read code is present, but the actual "write this code into a new file" is done inside the black box, so I know it is correct.